# HTML structure for screen sized elements

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to create properly the HTML structure of the following mockup:

[image]

**Requirements and conditions:**

1. The size of an item (pink or the black items) is the size of the device screen.
2. Each item represents a page.
3. It can be any device like desktop, tablets, smartphones.
4. Only one page will be shown at time!
5. Navigation, *not subject of my question and I'm just trying to offer as much information as possible*, will be done with click on arrows on desktop devices and by swiping on other devices.
6. There will be no scrollbar.
7. The content of any page can exceed the current size of the screen and if so, it will be marked inside the content with a slider or carousel functionality.
8. Any of the pages can contain other similar structures like the current one.

I'm not sure if all the points are super important to know to create the basic structure for the current mockup.

Is that okay to create the main starter element (pink) with `position: relative` and all the other elements with `position: absolute`? Also the size of the pages to be calculated with jQuery based on the current screen size? Or there isn't needed any jQuery for this? (`width: 100%` and `height: 100%` only by CSS ?)

This is the way I am thinking this HTML structure but I'm not so sure it is the best solution, so I tought it would be a good idea to listen other opinions too.

Comment: I had only directions and expected the same as answer, but the code from the below answer seems to be good and I don't have a better idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You approach is quite near to what is required, all the page div should be inside a container which needs to be relative, and childs should be absolute, As far as i can see, a simple markup would be enough to achieve this using view-port height and width in CSS , like below

**HTML**

```
<div id="cont">
    <div id="pink"></div>
    <div id="blk1"></div>
    <div id="blk2"></div>
    <div id="blk3"></div>
    <div id="blk4"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#cont{
  width: 100vw;
  height:100vh;
  position: relative;
}

#cont div{
  width: 100vw;
  height:100vh;
  background: #2c2c2c;
  margin:20px;
  position:absolute;
}

#pink{ background: #F00 !important; }
#blk1{ left: -100vw; }
#blk2{ top: -100vh; }
#blk3{ bottom: -100vh; }
#blk4{ right: -100vw; }
```

here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yauvc056/)

Comment: Thank you! I was expecting for some directions, but the code is useful too.

Comment: Happy to help :)